# archartengine : percentage for Y values

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to define percentages between Y values ?

I mean:

I have time value  "3.30" ; linechart puts ".30" as "30 %"

But I want to use 60 for 100% value ( for minutes) so ".30" will be shown as "50%"

It can be made :

```
minute = minute * 100 /60;
```

But I want to show my original time values on graphic also.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom labels on any of the axes:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, label);
```